# R Reading in Tweets Issue: Created_At is NA

Tags: r, date, datetime, twitter

I have a CSV file of my tweets, with the following columns:

```
created_at | text | lon | lat
```

I'm reading this in using:

```
tweets_df <- read.csv("mytweets.csv", header=TRUE, StringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But, when I type:

```
tweets_df$created_at
```

Everything is just NA.

This is an example of the same "created_at" entry:

```
Thu Sep 15 23:59:16 +0000 2016
```

Later on I was going to convert this to a more manageable format using one of these but I can't even read it in correctly... what am I doing wrong here?

```
time_format <- "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y"
tweet_df$created_at <- as.POSIXct(striptime(tweet_df$created_at, time_format, tz="GMT"), tz="GMT)
```

But yeah, could anyone help me figure out why they're just read in as NA?

EDIT: Fixed it; needed to do the following:

```
tweets_df <- read.csv("myweets.csv", header=TRUE, StringsAsFactors=FALSE, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

The fileEncoding = "latin1" fixed it!

Comment: what happens if you exclude `StringsAsFactors=FALSE` ?

Comment: Same problem, still have NA for that column (created_at)

Comment: See the helpfile `?strptime`. Certain format specifiers, such as `%z`, can only be used for *output* format (`POSIXt` to `character`).

Comment: But that doesn't address the read.csv issue with the vals being NA right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like he did post the answer on the question? A bit confusing for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use fileEncoding="latin1" in the read.csv. That fixed it!